# What is the standard practice in Page object Model for opening the browser In Automation Testing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, testng, ui-automation

In Page Object Model using selenium, should we open and close the browser for
1) Every test case
2) Every test suit
3) Whole test suit end to end (1 browser instance for all test cases)?

Problems with 3rd option are
1) I can't run test cases parallelly.
2) If a blocker issue occurs in some test case then it can hamper other test cases.

Problems with 1st and second options are 
1) It will take time to initiate and close the browser for every test case.

Comment: Option 1 every time for me. In any framework I've worked with the practice has always been to make it so that individual test cases can always be run in isolation, in case you only need to run certain test cases, and also to ensure there is nothing leftover from previous tests that could affect your results (cookies, saved sessions etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page object model doesn't address how the tests are run. It addresses where locators and methods related to a particular page are placed. What you want to look at is what are the best practices for unit tests and the like.

There are a ton of articles on the web dealing with this. Here's one to get you started. https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Best+Practices+for+Running+Tests